# Wordpress most recent articles

Tags: wordpress, postman, wordpress-rest-api

I'm new in wp-json. I want to list most-recent posts in wordpress site.

> "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[posts_per_page]=3"

url return 3 articles to the postman but articles date are not actual.

For example dates of the returned replies

> "2017-10-24T08:00:59" ,"2017-10-22T10:00:11", "2017-10-21T08:50:04"

... I would like similar dates to be returned. The website publishes many articles every day.

How can i get all the data of the day we are. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Since WordPress 4.7 the filter argument for any post endpoint was removed.
Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts).

You list the 3 most recent WP posts by doing:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=3&orderby=date&order=desc
```

Parameters:

`per_page`: Maximum number of items to be returned in result set. Default: 10

`orderby`: Sort collection by object attribute. Default: date

`order`: Order sort attribute ascending or descending. Default: desc

Comment: Thank you but this is not working right. When I wrote asc instead of desc, 1993.01.01 articles are turning. so it works correctly. but desc does not work right